Understanding task stream and speeding up Distributed Dask
I have implemented some data analysis in Dask using dask-distributed, but the performance is very far from the same analysis implemented in numpy/pandas and I am finding it difficult to understand the task stream and memory consumption.
The class that sets up the cluster looks like:
class some_class():
    
        def __init__(self,engine_kwargs: dict = None):
            self.distributed = engine_kwargs.get("distributed", False)
            self.dask_client = None
                    self.n_workers = engine_kwargs.get(
                "n_workers", int(os.getenv("SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK", os.cpu_count()))
            )
    
        @contextmanager
        def dask_context(self):
            """Dask context manager to set up and close down client"""
            if self.distributed:
                if self.distributed_mode == "processes":
                    processes = True
                dask_cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=self.n_workers, processes=processes)
                dask_client = Client(self.dask_cluster)
    
            try:
                yield
            finally:
                if dask_client is not None:
                    dask_client.close()
                    local_cluster.close()

And I have something like the following method, which does the analysis:
    def correct(self,
        segy_container: "SegyFileContainer",
        v_sb: int,
        interp_type: int = 1,
        brute_downsample: int = None,)
        """"
        :param segy_container: Container for the seg-y path and data
        :type segy_container: SegyFileContainer
        :param interp_type: Interpolation type either 1=linear or 3=cubic, defaults to 1
        :type interp_type: int, optional
        :param brute_downsample: If you wish to down sample the data to get a brute stack, defaults to None
        :type brute_downsample: int, optional
        :param v_sb: NMO velocity, defaults to 1500
        :type v_sb: int, optional
        :return: NMO corrected gather
        :rtype: pd.DataFrame
        """
        min_cmp = segy_container.trace_headers["CDP"].values.min()
        max_cmp = segy_container.trace_headers["CDP"].values.max()
        groups = segy_container.trace_headers["CDP"]
        cdp_series = segy_container.trace_headers["CDP"]

        cdp_dataarray = xr.DataArray(cdp_series, dims=["trace"])

        dg_cmp = segy_container.segy_file.data.groupby(cdp_dataarray)
        dt_s = segy_container.segy_file.attrs["sample_rate"]
        hg_cmp = segy_container.trace_headers.groupby(
            segy_container.trace_headers["CDP"]
        )
        segy_container.trace_headers["CDP"].iloc[hg_cmp.indices.get(100)]
        tasks = [
            delayed(self._process_group)(
                segy_container, cmp_index, dg_cmp, hg_cmp, v_sb, interp_type, dt_s
            )
            for cmp_index in range(min_cmp, max_cmp + 1)
        ]

        with self.dask_context() as dc:
            results = compute(*tasks, scheduler=dc)

    def _process_group(
        self,
        segy_container,
        cmp_index,
        dg_cmp,
        hg_cmp,
        v_sb: int,
        interp_type: int,
        dt_s: int,
    ):

        cmp = (
            segy_container.segy_file.data[dg_cmp.groups[cmp_index]]
            .transpose()
            .compute()
        )
        offsets = hg_cmp.get_group(cmp_index)["offset"]
        nmo = self._nmo_correction(
            cmp=cmp,
            dt=dt_s / 1000,
            offsets=offsets,
            velocity=v_sb,
            interp_type=interp_type,
        )
        return nmo

    def _nmo_correction(
        self, cmp, dt: float, offsets, velocity: float, interp_type: int
    ):
        nmo_trace = da.zeros_like(cmp)
        nsamples = cmp.data.shape[0]
        times = da.arange(0, nsamples * dt, dt)

        for ind, offset in enumerate(offsets):
            reflected_times = self._reflection_time(times, offset, velocity)
            amplitude = self._sample_trace(
                reflected_times=reflected_times,
                trace=cmp.data[:, ind],
                dt=dt,
                interp_type=interp_type,
            )

            if amplitude is not None:
                nmo_trace[:, ind] = amplitude

        return nmo_trace

    def _reflection_time(self, t0, x, vnmo):
        t = da.sqrt(t0**2 + x**2 / vnmo**2)
        return t.compute()

    def _sample_trace(self, reflected_times, trace, dt, interp_type):
        times = np.arange(trace.size) * dt
        times = xr.DataArray(times)  
        reflected_times = xr.DataArray(reflected_times, dims="reflected_times")

        out_of_bounds = (reflected_times < times[0]) | (reflected_times > times[-1])
        if interp_type == 1:
            amplitude = np.interp(reflected_times, times, trace)
        elif interp_type == 3:
            polyfit = CubicSpline(times, trace)
            amplitude = polyfit(reflected_times)
        else:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Error in interpolating sample trace. interp_type should be either 1 or 3: {interp_type}"
            )

        amplitude[out_of_bounds.compute()] = 0.0
        return amplitude

I have the same thing implemented using numpy and pandas, and the runtime is 3 secs. For Dask-distributed in the way shown it is taking around 15 mins. If I just use scheduler=processes and not the cluster it takes about 4 mins.
I understand there will be overhead in setting up and using the cluster, but am trying to understand how to improve the run time.
Looking at the diagnostics in the Dask dash give some quite confusing graphs:



I understand why there maybe more streams than the 10 workers I have created in this case, but am finding it hard to understand what exactly is going on here. I also dont understand why the memory usage is so high - as the file I am looking at is 715 Mb.
Any advice or insight on how to

Understand the task stream
Speed up the Dask-distributed code
Understand why the memory usage is so high

Would be very much appreciated!

Why are you trying to use Dask if process time is only 3s? Appart from that, it seems you are sending the big file on every delayed call, leading to a lot of data transfer and memory consumption. Also, you are probably launching tasks from tasks by seeing what is displayed on the Dashboard.

"probably launching tasks from tasks" - how would you tell? I would think that .compute() within a task should use the threaded scheduler is a client hasn't been explicitly created. Are you thinking the client itself is getting pickled and sent?

When your data fits easily into memory, it should be much faster to use your numerical package (numpy, pandas, xarray, ...) directly without dask.
The basic reason, is that to get a task to a worker, you must copy all the data it will need to work on, transfer it to the worker, have it do the job, and then reverse the process to get the result back. Many workers are, of course, doing this simultaneously. Here are a few things to keep in mind:

you are better off with tasks that load data in the worker rather than sending from the client
you are better off .compute()-ing on results that have been much aggregated to be small
the worker memory limit is set automatically, and typically 1/N of your global RAM where N is the number of worker threads; dask will by default kill/restart workers that reach the limit. This is probably what you are seeing, and accounts for the "curve to the right" in the task streams, as fresh new workers appear
the amount of memory required to do a numpy/pandas task is often several times the partition size, to account for various temporary copies

You might consider using the threaded scheduler for this particular workflow, since that avoids copying the underlying data and much of the overhead, but you will still have temporary arrays associated with several parallel tasks in memory at once.
Other possible solutions:

tune the number of workers/threads
use smaller partitions

Keep in mind, that none of this addresses what your actual code is doing, because I cannot follow it at all. You have compute() calls in multiple places, which suggests to me that you might have several dask roundtrips going on.

Thanks @mdurant. After removing the .compute() that I had dotted around the place (I had those in to see what was actually being computed to make sure it was doing the right thing) now iruns much more quickly (nothing like the numpy/pandas version but that is expected). The memory usage is still very large, so I'll try and figure out if I can reduce it any.
